# Logout issue Codecharge - Log out from one app logs out all

Tags: logout, codecharge

Good to see CCS is still alive and well.
Have two applications on the same site. Second app is Admin in a folder of main site.
Using different login variables for each. Different Cookie names.
Log out from main site, logs out Admin. Using link: logout_page.php?Logout=True

Tried changing variables.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new UserGroup for the Admin-pages only.